# setting a this.value in ng-init and accessing it from ng-class not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-init

I'm trying to attach a distinct value to child elements of elements created by ng-repeat.

```
div(ng-repeat=" element in array ")
    div(ng-init=" this.value='zero' " ng-class=" this.value === my.value ? 'match' : 'not' " )
    div(ng-init=" this.value='one1' " ng-class=" this.value === my.value ? 'match' : 'not' " )
```

The `$scope.my.value` is set dynamically, but as shown above, I want to test it against the `this.value` hard-coded to the element in its `ng-init`.

But this isn't giving me the results. Maybe `this.value` isn't attaching to the element. Am I doing something wrong (I don't know why I thought *`this`* would work), is there an alternative to do what I want?

I guess the crux of my question is: is there a `this`/equivalent for each element that I can pin some distinct values to?

Comment: @Mosho Dropping `this` makes both elements' class 'match', which I guess is because the `value` then is not distinct to each element, as I tried doing with `this`...

Comment: well, yeah, it's the same scope. There is a separate scope for each iteration of `ng-repeat`. if you want a scope for each of those divs, I suggest you make a directive. but you can just give the variables different names.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a controller on each element, and initialize their value using $index:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in array" ng-class=" value === my.value ? 'match' : 'not' " 
     ng-controller="elementController"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
module.controller('elementController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    if($scope.$index == 0){
        $scope.value = 'zero'
    }
    if($scope.$index == 1){
        $scope.value = 'one1'
    }
}]);
```